# Determining the time zone offset of UTC time in .Net

Tags: c#, utc, timezone-offset

The back-end is C# and SQL Server.

I save logging activity date times from different time zones in UTC in my DB. I need to populate a globally distributed front end so it localizes the logged UTC time based on where the front end is located, which will be known e.g. PT, ET. It also needs to handle daylight savings time which is where I'm running into difficulty.

As the UTC offset changes based on the time of the year because of daylight savings time, is there a way for me to find out what the UTC offset is in C# given that I know the date/time and the time zone.

Comment: I suspect that you shouldn't need to "find out" the offset and just let the underlying system take care of the conversion.  So if you have a `DateTime` value and two `TimeZoneInfo` objects (the source time zone, in this case UTC, and the target time zone known for displaying to the user) then you'd use something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way for me to find out what the UTC offset is in C# given that I know the date/time and the time zone

Technically you shouldn't *need* to find out this information, the underlying system clock/calendar/what-have-you should take care of it.  (I'm sure anybody who [has worked on date-time logic](http://nodatime.org) will attest to the fact that it is *non-trivial* to say the least.)

Ideally, any time you need to convert a time zone, you have three things:

1. A `DateTime` object representing the value to be converted.
2. A `TimeZoneInfo` object representing the known current format of the `DateTime` object (in this case UTC).
3. A `TimeZoneInfo` object representing the target time zone.

Given those things, any time you want to display the `DateTime` to a localized user, you'd use [something like `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform the conversion.  This should ideally be done as close to the UI as possible so that backing logic is always consistently performed in UTC.

Comment: Timezones are a Jon Skeet hard problem http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/09/30/the-mysteries-of-bcl-time-zone-data/ http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/